# Ajax after form submit doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('1');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/CorrectUrl/CorrectUrl",
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('2');
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    console.log(a);
                }
            });
        }, 100);
    });
```

And the url for the form is called and executed. The form returns value.
But CorrectUrl isn't getting called. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to stop the default action from occuring with `preventDefault()`

```
$('#my_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```